# How to save files via django serializers after processing them in my views?

Tags: python, django, pandas, django-rest-framework

I have a excel/csv file that I read using pandas once the user uploads the file. I process the file in my views.py and save them directly using the command `df.to_excel("filename.xlsx")` or `df.to_csv("filename.csv")`
Is there a way to save the files through django serializer?

I've tried `df.to_excel("filename.xlsx")` directly on the serializer data as shown on the code, but the file ends up writing to my disk directly instead of being saved via the serializer.

```py
data = {
            'file': df_template.to_excel(output_file_name, index=False),
            'created_for': project.id,
        }

outputrecord_serializer = OutputRecordSerializer(data=data)

if outputrecord_serializer.is_valid():
     #print('Check if serializer is valid')
     outputrecord_serializer.save()
     #print('saved')
else:
     print(outputrecord_serializer.errors)
```

Comment: Could you provide your serializer class? Also, not sure what you mean by "save the files through serializer".

Comment: `class OutputRecordSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = OutputRecord
        fields = '_all_'`

Comment: When you save files through the serializer, you pass the data and the serializer depending on the model saves the file at the 'media root' location. What I'm doing now is specifying an output path to the location and then writing file to the disk using `df.to_excel(outputpath + 'filename.xlsx')` . Also, by doing this, I can't get the files to display on the Django admin panel.